# Connecting to MySQL database in django using workbench

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

I've got a django project connected to a MySQL database as follows:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

on running `python manage.py syncdb`, it creates the database and on `runserver` the application runs perfectly and I'm able to input data into the models using the admin panel correctly.

However, on trying to connect to the database using MySQL Workbench, it gives me
`Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)` error.

I had created the database as follows:

```
Grant all on my_db.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'mypassword';
flush privileges;
```

Why would Workbench show me that error even though the server is running correctly? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Used the word pythong.

Comment: Are you trying connect with database by Workbench when server is running? Maybe there is some kind of locking mechanism.

Comment: @noisy, Thing is, I can connect to it using localhost/phpmyadmin when the server is running. Same thing should work in workbench but it gives me that problem. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but it got resolved by updating #port and #host into configuration file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'vres',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Looking at Database settings mentioned above its clear that values for  HOST: and PORT parameters are not defined and I would suggest you to try adding explicitly default host IP and default port address of your mysql connection.    Please first make sure that your system is not running any other mysql service e.g. phymyadmin/wamp/xamp

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your MySQL server is only listening to localhost.
In your `my.cnf` file, comment out `bind-address`.

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Restart your MySQL server and see if you can connect with Workbench.